# Electron (Windows) How does manual distribution work?

Tags: electron

I am trying to follow the instructions on this page: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution#manual-distribution however it is very vague and unclear.

I am trying to build an app that is simply an index.html with some static assets (JS, CSS, images.) There are no calls to server-side APIs from the client side.

The docs say to use this layout:

```
electron/resources/app
- package.json
- main.js
- index.html
```

But it's not working for me.

What is main.js? I assume this is the electron script that should create the main browser window and set the url to my local index.html, not something that is run within the webview window.

Why does it say index.html has to be there? I would think the URL to index.html is specified in main.js? (I have all client assets in a "public" folder.)

Why does it need a package.json? I have no scripts and don't use any additional npm modules.

I have tried a number of layouts but all that happens when I double-click electron.exe is that it exits immediately without any errors. From what I can tell it never executes my main.js script.

I can't find any additional resources on setting up a simple manual distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working after expanding the default_app.asar distributed with the Electron build. The instructions on the page linked above neglected to mention that the `package.json` should contain something like:

```
{
  "name": "electron",
  "productName": "Electron",
  "main": "main.js"
}
```

The only file that needs to be in resources/app is the `package.json` file. You can set `main` to the location of your your app's entry point script and you can put any other files wherever you want.